# for abelian $A\ncong \mathbb Z_2 ,\{e\} $ to finde a automorphism that is not trivial

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

let $A\ncong \mathbb Z_2 , \{e\}$ abelian group, i want to find a automorphism $\varphi\neq Id_A$.

i tried to define it such that for every $a\in A $  , $\varphi (a)=-a$. this definition will do unless for every $a\in A$  we will find that $a^2=e$. now here i tied to think maybe it can to be a vector space over $\mathbb Z_2$  and then to use maybe a permutation? we i dont know. i will be happy for some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost done. Denote $A$ with an additive notation. If $\forall x \in A, x+x=0$, then it is well defined the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector space structure on $A$
$$\lambda x = 
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
x & \mbox{ if } & \lambda = 1\\
0 & \mbox{ if } & \lambda = 0
\end{matrix}
\right.
$$
for $\lambda \in \mathbb{Z}_2, x \in A$.

Since $A \ncong \mathbb{Z}_2$, the dimension of $A$ must be at least $2$. Let $B$ a basis of $A$, $\sigma$ a permutation of $B$ which is not $id_B$. Then $\sigma$ induces a non-identical automorphism $f \in \operatorname{Aut} (A)$ as a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-vector space.

And clearly this is a non-identical automorphism of $A$ as a group.